# UITableViewDataSource not being invoked in Swift, Xcode 7 beta 2

Tags: swift, uitableview

This is a bizarre one, & I'm quite happy to be told that I've missed something obvious, but I can't see it.

Firstly, the UITableViewDataSource methods are not even showing up in autocomplete, then they're not called at runtime. Weirdly, the UITableViewDelegate methods are working on both counts.

Here's the (cut-down) code -

```
class PopupTable : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    private var tableView : UITableView

    init(rect: CGRect)
    {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: rect, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)

        super.init()

        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PopupCell")

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func show()
    {
        if let mainWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!
        {
            mainWindow.addSubview(tableView)
        }
    }


    // MARK: TableView Delegate & DataSource

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return myData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {        
        let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PopupCell")!

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "some text"

        return cell
    }
}
```

I have no problems getting this to work in a UIViewController, but that's not what I want here.

Comment: I suspect your PopupTable object is being released by ARC.  Show how you create it and use it in your view controller.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks, missing the obvious simple fix while looking for something complicated... Post it up as an answer & I'll accept it